# interesting null pointer exception at grails test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, nullpointerexception

I want to write unit tests for my grails app.

But there is a problem about `null` object pattern in groovy.

I create an instance using for :

```
KeywordClickPerformance performance = KeywordClickPerformance.forA("string").from(startDate).to(endDate)
```

But when using like this;

```
void testForA() {
    assertEquals "string", performance.keyword.name
}
```

after unit test execution, grails gives this exception:

```
"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object at "
```

I used `performance?.keyword?.name` for the solution, but it returns `null` because `performance` is `null`.

I didn't find a solution. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: i can't fully understand what other value you're waiting for, when performance is null?

Comment: I expected a string from KeywordClickPerformance, but performance may not be null

Answer (score 0):

you need to create performance in your test, or in setup.  Otherwise your forA method is not right...

Comment: we created performance with KeywordClickPerformance performance = KeywordClickPerformance.forA("string").... in the forA method perormance is null, already it's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

perfomance is not being created.  You need to add new in front of KeyworkClickPerformance on the right side of =   .  I think groovy will allow the chaining off of a constructor.  If not, you can do it in two lines

KeywordClickPerformance performance = new KeywordClickPerformance()
performance.forA("string").from(startDate).to(endDate)

Comment: ok, I tried this, but there is not the right solution.Thanks.